# SQL WHERE clause - Conditional filters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a query I want to work with the following logic (knowing full well it won't work as written):

```
select *
From orders
Where   if Value1 != 'TEST'
        (Value1 = @1)
        Else if Value2 != 'TEST'
        (Value2 = @2)
        Else 1=2
```

I don't think I can use a `Case...When` or `iif` since the value to filter the query on changes based on the outcome of condition. Any ideas?

Comment: what flavor of SQL ?

Comment: Why not use the standard AND/OR?

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure, that can be done with a dynamic sproc

Comment: sorry for not being descriptive enough! Using microsoft SQL server 2012, so T-SQL

Comment: Cant use and/or. If the first is true, I don't want to match on the second. If the first doesn't have good data, want to use the second only

Comment: Sorry, comments coming faster than I can respond, so thanks! unfortunately I'll have to plug this into some software where I cant reference stored procs... its been frustrating me

Comment: please search. this is a very commonly asked question. here is one answer from a basic search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978179/how-to-conditionally-filter-on-a-column-in-a-where-clause

Comment: That link doesn't help... in that one, like the others that I found, have the luxury of comparing two items to a single variable. What I'm looking for is: IF variable1 != test1 then variable1 = parameter1 ELSE If Variable2 != test2 then Variable2 = parameter2

Comment: Essentially, i feel like I need two where clauses, but only want to use one at a time depending on the data presesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is equivalent to:

```
Select *
From orders
Where (Value1 <> 'TEST' and Value1 = @1) OR
      (Value1 = 'TEST' and Value2 <> 'TEST' and Value2 = @2)
```

This is not 100% equivalent.  If `Value1` could be `NULL`, then the logic should take that into account:

```
Select o.*
From orders o
Where (Value1 <> 'TEST' and Value1 = @1) OR
      (COALESCE(Value1, 'TEST') = 'Test' and Value2 <> 'TEST' and Value2 = @2)
```

Comment: OK, you just made me feel stupid - I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!